# What does *= mean in python?

Tags: python

For example in this code:

```
def product(list):
    p =1
    for i in list:
        p *= i
    return p
```

I found this code, but I need to be able to explain each and every part of it.

Comment: Naming a variable `list` is a bad coding practice--it overrides the built-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually `p *= i` is the same as `p = p * i`.

Sometimes it can be different, and I think the explanations already posted aren't clear enough for that, so:

It can be different when p is a mutable object. In that case the in-place `*=` may modify the original object instead of creating a new one. Compare what happens to `q` in each of these:

```
>>> p = q = [2]
>>> p *= 5
>>> p
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>>> q
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

>>> p = q = [2]
>>> p = p * 5
>>> p
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>>> q
[2]
```

If can also be different when `p` is a complex expression with side effects as the in-place version only evaluates sub-expressions once. So for example:

```
aList[randint(0, 5)] *= 3
```

is not the same as:

```
aList[randint(0, 5)] = aList[randint(0, 5)] * 3
```

Answer (score 9):

It's shorthand for

```
p = p * i
```

It's analogous to the more frequently encountered `p += i`

Comment: That's true for this particular code chunk, but in general this is a bit of over-simplification.

Answer (score 5):

Taken from the first result in google:

> Multiply AND assignment operator, It multiplies right operand with the left operand and assign the result to left operand

`*=` is the same as saying `p = p * i`.

[This link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm) contains a list of all the operators in their various, wonderful combinations.

**Example**

A pseudo-code explanation of your code is as follows:

```
assume list := {4, 6, 5, 3, 5, 1}
p := 1.

for(each number in list)
    p = the current value of p * the current number.
    // So: 1 * 4, 4 * 6, 24 * 5, 120 * 3...

return p.
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not *exactly* the same as `p = p * i`:

```
>>> class A(int):
...     def __imul__(self, item):
...         print '__imul__ is running!'
...     
...     def __mul__(self, item):
...         print '__mul__ is running!'
>>> mynumber = A(10)
>>> mynumber *= 5
__imul__ is running!
>>> mynumber = A(10)
>>> mynumber * 5
__mul__ is running!
```

However the output is mostly the same, so you should probably treat it so

Comment: how can __mul__ be runing in your last line without a multiplication ?

Comment: @ychaouche oops sorry that's an error on my part

Comment: @Haidro This was a bit too complicated for a newbie :P

Comment: @GamesBrainiac It's helpful for future visitors as well :)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that `*=` has a separate implementation that could make it work differently from separate `*` and `=`.

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind the operator `a *= b` is to mean the same as `a = a * b`.  In most cases (as in yours) it will do exactly this, so it multiplies a variable with a value and stores the result in the variable again.

The notation using `*=` might be faster (depending on the classes involved), and it is, in any case, the clearer version, so it should be favored.  Its main advantage shows if the variable `a` is itself already a complex expression like `myGiantValueField[f(42)].getValue()[3]`:

```
myGiantValueField[f(42)].getValue()[3] = myGiantValueField[f(42)].getValue()[3] * 3
```

is certainly less readable and due to code doubling more prone to fixing-errors than

```
myGiantValueField[f(42)].getValue()[3] *= 3
```

In general, though, the operator `*=` calls the method `__imul__()` of the variable `a` and hands over the argument `b`, so it means exactly the same as `a.__imul__(b)` (which isn't as intuitive).

Why could there be a difference between `a = a * b` and `a *= b`?  Three reasons come two mind at once, but there might be more.

1. A class could implement *only* the `*=` operator (so `a * b` could be undefined although `a *= b` exists) due to performance aspects.  Multiplying a very large value (e. g. a giant matrix) with a number is sometimes better done in-place to avoid having to allocate memory for the result (which might at once after computation be copied into the original variable by the assignment).  That `a = a * b` is internally sth like `tmp = a * b` and `a = tmp`.
2. A class might find its use unintuitive using the direct multiplication, hence it could leave the `*` operator unimplemented.  An example might be a class representing the volume of the computer speaker.  Doubling the volume might make sense (`volumeKnob *= 2`) whereas computing it without using (assigning) it is not recommended (`x = volumeKnob * 2`? ← makes no sense as it does nothing).
3. If the type of the result of the multiplication differs from the type of `a`, I would not expect or recommend implementing the `*=` operator as it would be misleading.  An example might be if `a` and `b` are vectors whose multiplication result would be a matrix (or a number).  The name `__imul__` already suggests that it is meant for being applied iteratively, i. e. more than once.  But if `a`'s type changed, this would be problematic.